# Running two Docker Oracle containers on one Windows Machine

Tags: oracle, docker, devops

**1. What I am trying to achieve**

Using Docker for Windows (Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe) I would like to run in parallel two independent Oracle databases.
Image that I am using comes from [Oracle Container Registy](https://container-registry.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=113:4:102259360972296:::4:P4_REPOSITORY,AI_REPOSITORY,AI_REPOSITORY_NAME,P4_REPOSITORY_NAME,P4_EULA_ID,P4_BUSINESS_AREA_ID:8,8,Oracle%20Database%20Standard%20Edition%202,Oracle%20Database%20Standard%20Edition%202,1,0&cs=3RNUq8W4_6j6hKuXxhzc_-ulSMVdVqZJW2BBHo-REcwuIW1VtIKLnHMP1N0kAc20Q47h65TnUyTQLNFsAV0fZwg) and is a Oracle Database Standard Edition 2.

**2. How am I trying to achieve that**

I started one container and it is working fine (using default settings). Run command is:

```
docker run -d -p 1521:1521 -p 5500:5500 --shm-size="8g" --name=oracle --restart=always container-registry.oracle.com/database/standard
```

And this one is working perfectly fine. I can connect to DB using my app or DB administration tool.

Then I wanted to start different container using the same image and I used command:

```
docker run -d -p 1527:1521 -p 5507:5500 --shm-size="8g" --name=OraHib --restart=always container-registry.oracle.com/database/standard
```

Difference is in port numbers, name of container and I added also confuguration file as described in [documentation](https://container-registry.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=113:4:102259360972296:::4:P4_REPOSITORY,AI_REPOSITORY,AI_REPOSITORY_NAME,P4_REPOSITORY_NAME,P4_EULA_ID,P4_BUSINESS_AREA_ID:8,8,Oracle%20Database%20Standard%20Edition%202,Oracle%20Database%20Standard%20Edition%202,1,0&cs=3RNUq8W4_6j6hKuXxhzc_-ulSMVdVqZJW2BBHo-REcwuIW1VtIKLnHMP1N0kAc20Q47h65TnUyTQLNFsAV0fZwg) with different SID for this database.

**3. What are the results**

After waiting a quarter for my new container to start I am trying to connect to new database I receive error:

```
Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

Of course, double checked SID, so I am pretty sure that it is correct.

The container is running:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
6047148f17cd        container-registry.oracle.com/database/standard   "/bin/sh -c '/bin/ba…"   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       0.0.0.0:1527->1521/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5507->5500/tcp   OraHib
694120faf51c        container-registry.oracle.com/database/standard   "/bin/sh -c '/bin/ba…"   4 weeks ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:1521->1521/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5500->5500/tcp   oracle
```

What is in docker logs:

```
docker logs OraHib
User check : root.
Setup Oracle Database
Oracle Database 12.1.0.2 Setup
Tue Oct 6 11:48:21 UTC 2020

Check parameters ......
log file is : /home/oracle/setup/log/paramChk.log
paramChk.sh is done at 0 sec

untar DB bits ......
log file is : /home/oracle/setup/log/untarDB.log
untarDB.sh is done at 117 sec

config DB ......
log file is : /home/oracle/setup/log/configDB.log
ERROR : config DB failed, please check log /home/oracle/setup/log/configDB.log for details!
Tue Oct 6 11:48:21 UTC 2020
User check : root.
Setup Oracle Database
```

In mentioned `configDB.log` file there is:

```
Start Docker DB configuration
Call configDBora.sh to configure as oracle user
Argument(s) Error... Patch not present in the Oracle Home, Rollback cannot proceed
If the patch was applied using -no_inventory option, use -ph option
to specify the patch shiphome location. Use 'opatch rollback -help'
to get more information.

ERROR : ORA- errors detected, config DB ora failed, please check log /home/oracle/setup/log/configDBora.log for details!
Docker DB configuration failed ...
```

The last log file `configDBora.log` consists what is in [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ENWMi8Ch) - it is a bit longer than the first one.

***What I also tried***
Multiple different configurations of ports.
Changing SID of database
Tried on different computer

Does anyone have any clue why this seems impossible? I spent a lot of time on that and still don't have a single idea why it cannot run.

Comment: Sometimes I noticed that a Windows container won't be able to reach another Windows container.  I don't know why, but restarting the Docker windows service on the host machine, and then starting your containers again helps the inter-communication between windows containers on the same machine.

Comment: Thanks for that comment but I don't need them to see each other. I need other stuff to be able to connect to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the image has a bug when changing the `Oracle Enterprise manager` default port.
Just omit it and it will work:

```
docker run -d -p 1527:1521 --shm-size="8g" --name=OraHib
--restart=always container-registry.oracle.com/database/standard

docker run -d -p 1528:1521 --shm-size="8g" --name=OraHib2
--restart=always container-registry.oracle.com/database/standard
```

This is not perfect since this will deactivate EM (ie port is not available). But if you dont use it (like me) this won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

(sorry I can't comment yet so my only solution to ask something is by posting an "answer").

Maybe your 2 containers are trying to use the same volume?

I suppose Oracle images are based on the following repo:
https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance

Can you check if the official `Oracle Container Registry` image does not hard code a default volume for the data; by specifing a default `-v`option with a docker inspect on your running images.

`-v [<host mount point>:]/opt/oracle/oradata`

---

UPDATE

It seems that this feature is not enabled yet in this image.
If you look at the setup script inside a running container we can see that the listener port is hard coded with 1521 and does not use the exposed port :

```
su oracle
vi /home/oracle/setup/configDBora.sh
```

Port is hard coded:

```
[...]
echo "SSL_VERSION = 1.0"  >> $LSNR_ORA
# tnsnames.ora
TNS_ORA=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
echo "$DB_SID = \
  (DESCRIPTION = \
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521)) \
    (CONNECT_DATA = \
      (SERVER = DEDICATED) \
      (SERVICE_NAME = $DB_SID.$DB_DOMAIN) \
    ) \
  ) \
" >> $TNS_ORA
echo "$DB_PDB = \
  (DESCRIPTION = \
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521)) \
    (CONNECT_DATA = \
      (SERVER = DEDICATED) \
      (SERVICE_NAME = $DB_PDB.$DB_DOMAIN) \
[...]
```

I'll sugest you to try with another version, or use the script from [Oracle Github](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase).

Comment: I gave you the power of commenting ;-)
Unfortunately I am unable to share whole JSON from `docker inspect` but i cannot see any volume related info there except:
`"Volumes": null,`

Comment: @Zychoo thanks for the upgrade ! I'm currently downloading the image on my computer and test if I can reproduce your probelm.

Comment: i experience the same problem as you. I'll update my "answer"

Comment: Hi, you are right, the listener is set to listen on 1521 port inside the container but I think that you can map this port to any other port in host machine using `-p <hostPort>:1521` option in `docker run` command. I have no problems in connecting to listener on container on any port I set up on host. Listener is there, but problem is that there is no database started that he can route to.